# Relation onetoone in QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony4, query-builder

I'm trying to make a query with QueryBuilder for a delete already used object.
The correct Mysql query is:

```
SELECT * FROM token LEFT JOIN att_token ON token.id = att_token.id_token_id WHERE att_token.id_utilisateur_id IS null ORDER BY token.num_serie ASC
```

My QueryBuilder in my repository is:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $Token) {
  return $Token->createQueryBuilder('u')
  ->from('App\Entity\AttToken', 'att_token')
  ->LeftJoin('att_token.IdToken','attu')
  ->Where('att_token.IdUtilisateur IS null')
  ->orderBy('u.numSerie', 'ASC');
```

But I have no result, no error. I don't know where is my mistake...

I have a OneToOne relation between Token and AttToken entity, in AttToken I have the relation description but not in Token entity...

If someone have a idea ...

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I start to delete IdToken attribute on AttToken.
Then I use

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

To create it again and answer yes to

```
Do you want to add a new property to Token so that you can access/update AttToken objects from it - e.g. $token->getAttToken()? (yes/no) [no]:
```

Then my createQueryBuilder come simply like:

```
->LeftJoin('u.attToken','attu')
->Where('attu.IdUtilisateur IS null')
->orderBy('u.numSerie', 'ASC');
```

Have a nice day